# When is the old english letter Æ/æ modernised to A, E and AE?

Tags: orthography, early-modern-english, old-english, middle-english, ligature

The old english letter Æ/æ in various words have been modernised to either A (Æthelstan to Athelstan); E (Ælf to Elf, Æthelræd to Ethelred) and sometimes both A and E in the same word (Ælfræd to Alfred), sometimes the Æ is most commonly spelt as Ae (Æthelwulf to Aethelwulf according to the Britannica).

Is there an explanation or certain rules on how this occurred?

Or is this completely arbitrary?

Comment: As far as names go, there were ashes aplenty in OE names. Ælfwynn ("Elf Friend"), Æthelstan Æthling (Noble Stone the Noble One), Æþelræd Unræd's ("Noble Counsel the Ill-Advised") son by  Ælfgifu ("Elf Gift"), and so on. Interestingly, sometimes the ash in a name was split to AE in those times, as in Ælfred the Great's crown jewel, which bears the motto "AELFRED MEC HEHT GEWYRCAN" ("Ælfred  had me made/crafted/worked"). (Word separation for clarity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Jewel#/media/File:The_Alfred_Jewel_(side_view).jpg.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### preface

Since this is an area where certain confusions are possible, I want to start by noting that the Old English letter Æ/æ (named *ash*) represented a sound that is etymologically unrelated to the ligature *Æ/æ* used in words derived from Latin (where it represents what was originally a diphthong sound in Latin). In both cases the grapheme *Æ/æ* developed from an original sequence of the letters *a* and *e*, *ae*, but in Old English this was considered its own letter (unlike in Latin).

The letter Æ/æ in Old English represented a monophthongal vowel that could be either of two lengths: short (transcribed in the International Phonetic Alphabet as /æ/) or long (transcribed in the International Phonetic Alphabet as /æː/, often written in dictionaries and modern editions of Old English texts as *ǣ* to distinguish it from the short vowel).

In words that were transmitted orally from Old English to the present (that is, in inherited vocabulary), short Old English /æ/ generally turned into the Middle English vowel /a/, and long Old English /æː/ generally turned into the Middle English vowel /ɛː/, but other developments are possible-it's complicated.

### *elf*

I believe "elf" is an inherited word, but it shows an alternative outcome of short Old English /æ/. The history of the word *elf* is a little complicated as it involves a sequence that varied in its treatment between different [dialects of Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_phonology#Dialects). The development of the *e* found in modern English is summarized by Alaric Timothy Peter Hall as follows:

> In the West Midlands, Anglian *æ* developed before /lC/ as in other contexts: unaffected by second fronting (Hogg 1992a, §5.87), it coalesced with *a,* giving the forms *alue, aluen* found in both manuscripts of Laȝamon’s Brut. However, in the other reflexes of Anglian dialects, Old English *æ* from */AlCi/ became *e* giving *elf* (Luick 1914–40, I §366; Jordan 1974, §62; cf. Hogg 1997, 207–12). This was more or less identical with the South-Eastern *elf,* so it was natural that *elf* became the standard English form, being the root used by Chaucer and almost all other later Middle English texts, regardless of their place of origin.

(page 214, "Appendix 1: The Linguistic History of Elf", in *[The Meanings of Elf and Elves in Medieval England](https://www.academia.edu/2977257/The_meanings_of_elf_and_elves_in_medieval_England),* dissertation, October, 2004)

### names

For words that were not truly inherited but were modified from the Old English form, explanations will likely be relatively word-per-word.

Here is what I've got so far:

*Athelstan* seems to have been used since at least the 16th century (Google Books links: [1](https://books.google.com/books?id=-gEIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA24&dq=Athelstan&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9jNrkv9j8AhV4LUQIHT7kA94Q6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=Athelstan&f=false), [2](https://books.google.com/books?id=NUYDAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PT4&dq=Athelstan&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9jNrkv9j8AhV4LUQIHT7kA94Q6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=Athelstan&f=false); it could well be even older) and thus is not an especially recent rendering of this name. I don't know why *A* was used. There are also texts of a similar age that use the form *Ethelstan* ([1](https://books.google.com/books?id=QUlhAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA240&dq=Ethelstan&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4nf3H0tj8AhUJIUQIHQU8DNoQ6AF6BAgREAI#v=onepage&q=Ethelstan&f=false), [2](https://books.google.com/books?id=QoOET2aO9uAC&pg=PA481-IA1&dq=Ethelstan&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4nf3H0tj8AhUJIUQIHQU8DNoQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=Ethelstan&f=false), both in Latin).

I think the ending -ræd is generally preferred to be rendered as *-red,* but I'm not sure why. Brainstorming ideas:

- this was in Old English pronounced *rǣd*, with a long vowel that did not develop to a modern English "a" sound (unlike short æ) and which showed dialectal variation already with an "e" sound (Wiktionary records *rēd* as an Anglian variant of the independent word *rǣd*). If the sound of *ǣ* survived at all in speech, it would be expected to develop to an *e* sound not an *a* sound.
- Alternatively, as the second element of a name, we would expect the vowel in *-ræd* to be more subject than a vowel in an initial syllable to being reduced in quality; in both modern English and Old English, reduction often produces an e-like vowel ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_phonology#Monophthongs): "In unstressed syllables, [...] /æ, e, i/ were reduced to /e/"; this refers to short vowels specifically, but [Old English could shorten vowels in unstressed syllables](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96456/what-did-we-gain-in-return-for-the-loss-of-phonemic-vowel-length-from-old-englis/100158#100158)). In practice, I think *Alfred,* *Ethelred* are generally pronounced by modern English speakers with a reduced vowel in the final syllable. This sound might be better represented by the spelling with *e* than with *a.*

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "inherited," but "Elf" as *Ælf* crops up in many, many Anglo-Saxon names. See my comment to OP's answer, for example.