# Which words are pronounced with an /ɑː/ or /æ/ depending on dialect?

Tags: pronunciation

Certain English words are pronounced with two different vowels depending on the dialect of the speaker, namely with /ɑː/ or /æ/ (in IPA notation).  These include:

> can't, last, fast, past, path, vast, dance

Can you point me to a list of all common words with this property?

I recently heard the word “path” in a sound recording pronounced as /pæθ/, and didn't recognize it despite repeatedly listening.  I was aware that “can't” has two pronunciations, but I didn't know this about all these words.    I am asking this question so that in the future I have less trouble understanding such words.

Update: for search, here is a list of some such words that may be similar, based on the answer: advance, advantage, after, answer, ask, aunt, branch, brass, can't, cast, castle, chance, class, command, contrast, dance, demand, disaster, draft, enhance, example, fast, glass, glance, grant, graph, grass, half, last, laugh, mask, master, nasty, pass, past, path, photograph, plant, rather, sample, shan't, staff, task, vast.

Comment: Is this the BrE [trap/bath split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_short_A#Trap.E2.80.93bath_split)?

Comment: There is no such list. The sounds differ in different countries and in different parts of those countries. You haven't even specified the country.

Comment: @chasly: why would I need a country? I want to listen to English speakers from any country and try to understand them.  I believe the particular speaker I mention in the question is from the US though.

Comment: @Mitch: yes, it appears to be.  That article also gives a mostly complete list, so perhaps make that an answer.

Comment: For RP British English, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_short_A#Trap.E2.80.93bath_split_in_Received_Pronunciation) is the list. Americans pronounce almost all of these with /æ/ (*aunt* is pronounced in a few regions with /ɑː/. For other dialects, as @chasly says, who knows what happens.

Comment: @PeterShor Some also pronounce 'aunt' as /ɔnt/. See  http://english.stackexchange.com/a/96439/4972 (and your comment there).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are hearing is the infamous [***trap–bath* split**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap-bath_split).

Some accents (like GenAmE) do not distinguish the vowels in trap and bath (both /æ/). But many BrE (RP and mainstream) and Oceanic (AusE, NZE, SAE) make a distinction. In contexts before /f, s, θ, ns, nt, ntʃ, mpl/, the /æ/ changes to /ɑː/.

So it depends on which country you’re in. *Trap* sounds mostly the same in AmE and BrE, but *bath* sounds ‘Englishy’ in BrE to Americans (and vice versa to the English).

The [Wikipedia article on the phonological history of English short ‘a’](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_short_A) and in particular its [*trap–bath* split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap-bath_split) article give the rule, lots of examples, and the many exceptions.

Comment: Here in the East Midlands, central England, the vowels in trap and bath are the same. They are /æ/. Me myself, I consider this perfectly mainstream, even though I don't speak that way myself.